# Passing ptr to returned std::string

Tags: c++, stdstring

Is this code safe?  Just because it runs with no errors, I'm concerned I'm setting a trap for myself.

```
void targetMethod( const char *arg );
std::string helperMethod( char *text ) { return std::string( text ); }

targetMethod( helperMethod().c_str() );
```

helperMethod() returns a std::string, and the calling code gets its underlying char*, and passes it to targetMethod().  I'm concerned that the returned string is temporary, so taking its underlying char* is dangerous.  So instead I should do something like this:

```
std::string myTemp = helperMethod( "hello" );
targetMethod( myTemp.c_str() );
```

Comment: Thanks, Cody. I need to sharpen my searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon what `targetMethod` does. If it stores the pointer away for later use, then no, it's not safe. But if it just uses it for the duration of the function call, then yes, it is safe. The lifetime of the string extends to the end of the full expression in which it is created.

Answer (score 2):

The temporary will live until the end of the expression (until the semicolon) so it is safe.

Having said that, I'm not sure why you need helperMethod at all since you can construct a std::string from a const char *.

Comment: "so it is safe" -- as long as `targetMethod` doesn't save a copy the pointer.

Comment: Yes.  The other answers added the "copy the pointer" caveat and are correct.

Comment: helperMethod() does more in the real world; it looks like it does in the example only to show what's happening.